# Consistent segmentation fault on recursive appending and new node creation in a Linked List C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I got a struct with 2 fields (`int` and `char*`) and I should create a list containing nodes of this type, problem is recursive algorithms seem correct but every time I compile it gives me a `SIGSEGV` error due to the assignment new_node->data->number = stud->number, more specifically it results data = {struct fields* | 0x0} NULL and next = {struct node* | 0x0} NULL. Any Help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct fields{
    int number;
    char *name;
};

struct Node {
    struct fields *data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node *newNode(struct fields* data);
struct Node* insertEnd(struct Node* head, struct fields* data);
struct Node* insertEnd(struct Node* head, struct fields* data);
void traverse(struct Node* head);
void init_fields (struct fields* stud);

// Allocates a new node with given data
struct Node *newNode(struct fields* data) {
    struct Node *new_node = malloc (1000*sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->data->number = data->number;
    new_node->data->name = data->name;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

struct Node* insertEnd(struct Node* head, struct fields* data){

    if (head == NULL)
        return newNode(data);

    else
        head->next = insertEnd(head->next, data);
    return head;
}

void traverse(struct Node* head){
    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    printf("\n%d %s\n", head->data->number, head->data->name);
    traverse(head->next);
}

int main(){
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    struct fields* stud = malloc(1000* sizeof(*stud));
    init_fields (stud);
    if (stud == NULL){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("\nInsert number: ");
    scanf("%d", &stud->number);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nInsert name: \n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", stud->name);
    head = insertEnd(head, stud);
    printf("\nInsert number: ");
    scanf("%d", &stud->number);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nInsert name: \n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", stud->name);
    head = insertEnd(head, stud);
    traverse(head);
}
void init_fields (struct fields* stud){
    stud->number = 0;
    stud->name = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: When you assign `new_node->data->number = data->number;`, where does `new_node->data` point?

Comment: @ak27 Why is the data member data  struct fields *data; defined as a pointer?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allocate `data`

```
struct Node *newNode(struct fields* data) {
    struct Node *new_node = malloc (1000*sizeof(*new_node));
    new_node->data = malloc(sizeof(*new_node->data));
    new_node->data->number = data->number;
    new_node->data->name = data->name;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}
```

In the future, you can find where exactly the problem was using `gdb` or `lldb`. It will point you to the exact line, and the problem is obvious from there.

Comment: thanks for the advise I got it know, but I don't know why right now it prints always the same ' name ' for all the nodes (the last one inserted)

Comment: That’s because you’re using the stud pointer to pass the data. You’re assigning the address of the name, so when you change stud’s value later, that change is reflected in the earlier nodes as well. You should use strdup(), or modify your function signatures to pass the name/number directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
struct Node *new_node = malloc (1000*sizeof(*new_node));
```

you are only allocating memory for new_node. What about this field?

```
struct fields *data;
```

It must be initialized somehow.

Comment: alright thanks, but now the names printed at the end are all the same (the last name inserted change all the others)